# Clear JTable with data retrieve from database using JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

just beginning my hands on Java and badly needs your help. I have a JComboBox that retrieves data from a database and displaying it in a JTable. 
My problem is when I select to **Students**, it displays the data about Students and when selecting to another option just like **Teacher**, it also display data about the Teacher but it is appended on the data displayed by Students. I wonder how can I display the data of **Students only** and  same with others.

Below is the code I used. Maybe I'm missing something.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class VisibilityTool extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public VisibilityTool() {
    initComponents();
}


//Generate
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    eMail = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    comBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    emailText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    buttonGenerate = new javax.swing.JButton();
    progressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
    selectEnvironment = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    dataTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    file = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    exit = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    help = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    about = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("[Trax] Data Visibility Tool");
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setFocusCycleRoot(false);
    setForeground(java.awt.Color.black);

    eMail.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    eMail.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Bright", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    eMail.setText("E - mail address :");

    comBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Select . . .", "Students", "Teachers", "Directors" }));
    comBox.setToolTipText("'Choose the database to query'");
    comBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            comBoxActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    emailText.setToolTipText("'Put you e-mail address here'");
    emailText.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            emailTextActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonGenerate.setText("GENERATE");
    buttonGenerate.setToolTipText("'GENERATE'");
    buttonGenerate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonGenerateActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    selectEnvironment.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    selectEnvironment.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Bright", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    selectEnvironment.setText("Select Environment :");

    dataTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "ID", "Name", "Surname", "Age"
        }
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    dataTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(dataTable);
    dataTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    dataTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    dataTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
    dataTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);

    file.setText("File");
    file.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            fileActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    exit.setText("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    file.add(exit);

    jMenuBar1.add(file);

    help.setText("Help");
    help.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            helpActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    about.setText("About");
    about.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            aboutActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    help.add(about);

    jMenuBar1.add(help);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 483, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(buttonGenerate)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(eMail, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                                    .addComponent(emailText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 325, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(selectEnvironment, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(comBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 325, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(selectEnvironment, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(comBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(eMail, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(emailText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(buttonGenerate)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void comBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Select . . .") {


    } else if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Students") {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();  
    String sql = "select * from students";
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});

        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    } else if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Teachers"){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
    String sql = "select * from teachers";
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});

        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    } else if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Directors") {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
    String sql = "select * from directors";
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});

        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

1) define `TableModel` only once time (meaning code lines)

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
```

2) remove all row from `TableModel` with reversal way

```
if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        model.removeRow(i);
    }
}
```

3) then add new rows from `ResultSet`

4) this code have got issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and all GUI is un_responsible untill `ResultSet` ended, on `Exceptions` from `ResultSet` only `Mouse hover_over` the `JTable's` rows refreshing GUI, better would be invoke `ResultSet` from [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) or `Runnable#Thread`

5) please write code by your hands, because for 90pct of potential answerers (inc. me) is not possible to runs generated code from some IDE and without definitions for local variables

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise answer Sir. I just thought it is better and easy to write programs using IDE's which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Before adding remove all the old values (rows?) from the model. Use `public void removeRow(int row)` method of model.

Answer (score 0):

Some day before I wrote a TableModel, here it is:

```
public class MovieSearchResultTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 46L;

    private List<MovieSearchModel> movieSearchModels;
    private ComponentConstant.ColumnName[] columns = ComponentConstant.Column.MOVIE_SEARCH_RESULT_TABLE;

    public int getRowCount() {
        return movieSearchModels.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return columns[columnIndex].getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columns[columnIndex].getClass();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Object returnValue = new Object();
        switch(columnIndex) {
            case 0: 
                returnValue = movieSearchModels.get(rowIndex).getName();
                break;
            case 1: 
                returnValue = movieSearchModels.get(rowIndex).getReleased();
                break;
            case 2: 
                returnValue = movieSearchModels.get(rowIndex).getLanguage();
                break;
            case 3: 
                returnValue = movieSearchModels.get(rowIndex).getRating();
                break;
            case 4: 
                returnValue = movieSearchModels.get(rowIndex).getCertification();
                break;
            case 5: 
                returnValue = movieSearchModels.get(rowIndex).getImdb_id();
                break;
        }       
        return returnValue;
    }

    public List<MovieSearchModel> getMovieSearchModels() {
        return movieSearchModels;
    }

    public void setMovieSearchModels(List<MovieSearchModel> movieSearchModels) {
        this.movieSearchModels = movieSearchModels;
    }
}
```

It is complicated. But the basic logic is, it has a list of object `movieSearchModels`. Its of type `MovieSearchModel` and the method `getValueAt()` populates the table. When I need to change the TableModel, I extract the model from table and set new value to `movieSearchModels`, then fire `fireTableDataChanged` with the help of TableModel. Like:

```
List<MovieSearchModel> movieSearchModels = ModelUtils.getMovieSearchModels(movieSearchResults);
MovieSearchResultTableModel movieSearchResultTableModel = (MovieSearchResultTableModel) ModelFactory.getMovieSearchResultTableModel();
movieSearchResultTableModel.setMovieSearchModels(movieSearchModels);
movieSearchResultTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

If you have any doubts you can ask.

Comment: never, really never call TableModel rellated events ouside of TableModel (fireTableDataChanged()), as I mentioned earlier please ask questions here how JTable and TableModel works, here are concentraded a few excelent Swing Gurus that understood .... +1 against potential donw_voting

Comment: I guess its getting more complicated for a beginner like me. I tried the `model.fireTableDataChanged();` but it doesn't display the data.

Comment: @mKorbel -  I agree, I'm thinking where and how I can use this code `model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();`

Do you have any idea about this Sir?

Thanks!

Comment: -1 invalid model implementation: it's the job of the _model_ to notify its listeners on change (vs. doing so from the outside)

Comment: @Karl you have a lots of issues with code compositions, let's this job for DefaultTableModel, follows with code from my 2nd. point